When can we apply simplicity? Only under other equal conditions or whenever we want?
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor
There are two versions of simplicity here:

Only when conditions are equal?

Whenever we want?


In the last question I asked about the Wikipedia article and asked for clarification. But the question was closed

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Occam's Razor is a crude heuristic for guessing the outcome of statistical predictions. Occam used the principle of "not multiplying entities" rather than statistical methods because statistics hadn't been invented yet. (So did most other scholars from antiquity through the 17th century, especially the medieval scholastics. Occam didn't invent the principle, his name just got pasted onto a common axiom centuries after his death.)
Note: "Multiplying" meaning "creating more and more while keeping the original". The linguistic parallel to the arithmetic of numerical probabilities is a happy accident.
We live in the centuries after statistics has been completely figured out and have no need for medieval approximations to them. The Razor remains occasionally useful as a quick and dirty substitute when we don't really care about being right; or when we're trying to sell books to general audiences, who are likely to disengage from the text the second they see a line of grade school algebra.

So we don't need to use Occam's razor to choose between solipsism and the existence of other minds?

@Arnold A priori commitments cannot be argued for or against, they're just what they are. You get to choose whether to have a useless one that rejects all knowledge except for the brute fact of the I-sense as spurious illusion (including the knowledge that you have chosen the useless one that rejects all knowledge as spurious illusion), or a useful one which tentatively accepts perceptions at face value until falsified. Neither statistical arguments nor crude heuristics for those statistical arguments are applicable.

Please explain in a little more detail.

Bad take. Without Occam’s razor, there is no reason for me to prefer the theory that there is an invisible goblin controlling my mother’s movements in front of me than the theory that my mother is moving by herself. It is certainly not limited to statistics

Can I just rely on philosophers and scientists and say that I do not believe that a small number of entities is a reason to believe in solipsism because scientists and philosophers think so. Will it be circular reasoning? Will it be rational?

Occam's Razor only applies when other things are equal.
Even the Wikipedia stated this: "This philosophical razor advocates that when presented with competing hypotheses about the same prediction and both hypotheses have equal explanatory power, one should prefer the hypothesis that requires the fewest assumptions".
The "simplest explanation is the correct one" is just layman's misinterpretation.

Please explain how the justification for why we believe that a small number of entities is not a reason to believe in solipsism should look like? I just want to know what I should say to myself when I ask myself why a small number of entities is not a reason to believe in solipsism? It should be the answer: "Because simplicity is used only under equal conditions"? How do you discard a small number of entities?

Because simplicity is only used when other things are equal. Here other things aren't equal. Solipsism can't be supported by occam's razor.

That is, does not the small number of entities in itself make solipsism more likely? Am I wrong? That is, only when two explanations are equally convincing can we apply simplicity?

Yes. Small number of entities is not a good reason to believe in solipsism. And simplicity can only be applied when other things are equal.

Check my comment on the main question.

I'm not answering the same question over and over again.

@Arnold okay, this is the last time I will answer this question. It's not CiRcUlAr ReAsOnInG. And yes, it's rational.

@Arnold why do you keep asking the same stupid question even though people have answered it before?
